# How can you annotate or club info into ELF core files on Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded, gdb, core-dump

For debugging core files it would be useful to add additional
information into a core file at the time it is generated.

I'm currently using  /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern to run a 
'dumb' script that records the core file and additional information
into a secondary file - but I'm curious if there might be some
advanced technique that modifies the core file itself to include
arbitrary data or some better workflow for including pertinent
information.

I don't have the ability to use google's breakpad (unsupported arch), so I'm
somewhat limited to the vanilla options available to dumping raw core files.

The assumption is that the core is non-fatal for the overall system but
rather just a single service that can be restarted successfully.

The system I'm working on is limited in storage, so the prospect of 
dumping a 500 meg core file out and then tarring it and additional files up into another archive (taking up another ~500 megs is not an ideal solution.)